# How does composer know symfony environment

Tags: symfony, composer-php

i try to deploy an app in "integration" environment but after the "composer update" command, the parameters.yml file generated doesn't contains may integration parameters

Here is what i did :
I created a "config_integ.yml" file in app/config with :

```
# app/config/config_integ.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters_integ.yml }
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
```

the parameters_integ.yml file contains parameters for integration environment. example of the beggining :

```
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: test_integ
    database_user: root
```

the parameters.yml.dist contains these parameters with default values :

```
parameters:
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     symfony
    database_user:     root
```

How can i tell to composer to take the parameters_integ.yml file to build the parameter.yml file ? Because i will have a prod environment after, i can't write my parameters in parameters.yml.dist file.

Tell me if you need other informations

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can this help? https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html

Comment: i read this, but it doesn't explains how to tell composer to build the parameters.yml file correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You should include **composer.json** and **composer.lock** in your VCS

2) You should not include **parameters.yml** in your VCS

3) When deploying Sf application you should use **composer install**

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#c-install-update-your-vendors
- difference between **composer install** and **composer update** (+ **composer.lock**): https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/composer-its-all-about-the-lock-file

4) I can think of a few ways for creating **parameters.yml** in the integration environment:

- you manually create **parameters.yml** file and place it beside **parameters.dist.yml**

or

- if there is no **parameters.yml** or **parameters.yml** has some missing parameters, when you run **composer install**, you will be prompted to enter missing parameters and **parameters.yml** will be created/updated during the **composer install** process

or

- you can have an **app/config/parameters** folder containing **parameters_prod.yml** and **parameters_integ.yml** files, and one of those files is automatically copied into **parameter.yml** file during deployment (most complicated solution)

---

If you want integration environment to be accessible via a browser, you should also create a front controller for it. Copy the **web/app.php** file to **web/app_integ.php** and edit the environment to be integration:

```
// web/app_integ.php
// ...

// change just this line
$kernel = new AppKernel('integ', false);

// ...
```

More info at https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#creating-a-new-environment

---

And the answer to the question from the title, "How does composer know symfony environment" - **I think composer has no idea about Sf environment** :)

The composer has **require-dev** option for packages that you do not need in your production, packages required for running tests (phpunit for example), some debugging stuff during development, etc.
For an example this is how one of my **composer.json** files looks like:

```
...
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "nelmio/alice": "^2.1",
    "deployer/deployer": "^4.0"
},
...
```

If I run `composer install --no-dev`, these packages won't be installed in the vendor directory.

But, how Sf knows when to include/omit some packages in the app.

That is defined inside **AppKernel.php**.

In the **composer.json**, under "require-dev" key I defined that I don't want doctrine fixtures in production.

So, inside **AppKernel.php** I put these lines of code:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
    ...
    $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
}
```

And if I run my app in production mode, there will not be DoctrineFixturesBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to set your default parameters in your `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` file.

See this link:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#canonical-parameters

When you run:

```
composer update
```

it will use the `parameters.yml.dist` and overwrite the `parameters.yml` with the values in the `dist` file.

Comment: if you run "composer update" when deploying, it will also update your packages. i saw in this link that the good workflow is to use composer install (https://adamcod.es/2013/03/07/composer-install-vs-composer-update.html)

Comment: I'm not certain what you need to do in your deployment environment, this can be a complex thing. Take [a look at this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html). Yes update is used for updating, etc... Command should be fairly obvious.