# Symfony deploying: RuntimeException in DebugClassLoader.php line 258:

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

Hello I have trouble by deploying my Symfony Projekt to my hoster.

I use: Symfony 2.8 with php 7.1.6

I do the following steps :

```
1. made a "composer update" on the project
2. cleaning the cache: "php app/console cache:clear -e prod"
3. Upload the files to the hoster
```

I copy the structure like on my system:

```
- htdocs-Folder
   - app
   - bin
   - src
   - vendor
   - test
   - web
```

When I open the website with: www.mydomaine.com/web/app_dev.php I get the following message:

[screenshort - error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BftPt.png)

Have anyone an idea why ?

THX

Comment: You have cleared production cache. Try to clear and dev cache also.

Comment: And please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000371/how-does-composer-know-symfony-environment/41013108#41013108

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to delete (make empty) the "prod"-cache folder manually, the command to clear the cache was not enough.